# How to use a function's class between 2 projects through a web service.?

Tags: java, web-services

This is the situation: I have 3 projects, one java project that containt some classes with some variables, procedures and functions; one web project and one web-service project that it connect the 2 others projects (web and java).

I can´t comunicate the web project and the java class project, only through web service project.

I want to use the functions and procedures of the java class project. So, in the web service, i import the java project and i create a web service function that do something and return a List. In the web Project i can create a Object from the Java Project to comunicate the web project with the web Service project, but when i want to use the functions and the procedures or variables of that class in the web project..... i can`t do that because i think the WSDL generated dont contain the functions of the class.

How can i solve that?

Thank you so much!

Comment: No ideas? If anybody know if its possible out not, please post it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create another web service with the proceder that you need or add the procedure to the web service that you already use.

Comment: The problem is i need to have access to the variables of the class in the Java Project too. And i need a structure like a List<Class> so the web service return a lot of information and return variable per variable its....

Comment: Then you can try to use RMI instead of the a Web Service.

Comment: The problem is the Web Service is used with other aplications and its the central stone of a big system. I have to use the web service yes or yes heheh. But thanks you so much for your opinion :)